# dart-polymer: failed to load resource using core-elements

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dart-editor

I want to use the core-scaffold element from the core-elements package. I imported

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-item.html">
```

into my html file. If i want to run the website i get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:8080/packages/core_elements/core-scaffold.html
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:8080/packages/core_elements/core-header-panel.html
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:8080/packages/core_elements/core-menu.html
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:8080/packages/core_elements/core-item.html
```

I also use some elements from the page-elements package without any problems...

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: Test
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  polymer: ">=0.15.0 <0.16.0"
  core_elements: ">=0.3.0 <0.4.0"
  paper_elements: ">=0.4.0 <0.5.0"
transformers:
- polymer
```

I tried to delete and reload the core-elements package with pub get. But it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

ok solved the problem. In the Polymere guide they used "-" in the links. The packages which the dart editor downloads use "_"  in the links.

So its not core-header-panel. Its core_header_panel.

Comment: Dashes in file names is against the Dart style guide.